# Using a TableName instead of Named Range in Excel datasource SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, vba

In Excel VBA, I am using Excel as datasource for some queries.
I am using the query as

```
SQL = "Select * from   [NameRange1]"   - This works
```

But, I want to use a table name instead of Namerange(Excel 2007 Tables). How do I use that?
I tried `"select * from [Table1]"` and I also tried creating a Namerange for this table1 and it didn't work either..

any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say whether you're using DAO or ADO to connect, but I don't think it matters.  I don't think it's possible to refer to a Table.  All the documentation I've seen lists three types of ranges: an entire sheet [Sheet1$], a named range[NameRange1], or an unnamed range [Sheet1$A1:B10].

I am able to give an Excel 2010 table a named range that includes the header and that works just like any other named range, and it changes size with the addition of rows.  Make sure that if it's a sheet-level named range you do it like [Sheet1$NameRange1].

The best information I found on doing it with ADO is here: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=217783